# Is running speed an illusion?

Tags: temple-run-2

In Temple Run 2, there seems to be the sensation that the running speed increases on long uninterrupted runs, in terms of turns coming up faster, being able to jump farther, and picking up coins more quickly.  But in terms of the posted distances that appear, those seems to be accumulated at a steady rate not connected to the apparent running speed.

That is, whether I've just started a run or have been 20k meters without a stumble, the amount of time it takes to go from one distance sign to the next (500 meters) always seems to be about the same (15 seconds.)  If there is a boost powerup or ability, it always seems to be about 5 or 6 seconds between the 500m signposts that appear, not connected to how long its been going or how fast it seems.

Has anyone done more careful measurements about the running speed increasing?  It seems to be not reflected in terms of the amount of time it takes to travel a fixed distance of 500 meters.  My impression is that the signposts are just counting time, not distance.